# How to close all sockets using socket.io and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I saw this code somewhere which can close all existing open sockets

```
if (io && io.sockets && io.sockets.sockets) {
    io.sockets.sockets.forEach(function(s) {
        s.disconnect(true);
    });     
}
```

I call this method when process is on `sigterm` or `sigint`

But somehow, there is still an existing node process running in the background after pressing ctrl+c and running the code `ps -A | grep node` I have this output

> 3605 pts/0    00:00:00 node

How can I close this socket without the need to kill it?

Please tell me if you need more information and I will gladly edit my question, thanks!

**Edit:**
I realized that sockets can at times be disconnected but when there are changes in my code, node (particularly nodemon) reconnects at a specific socket (which was recently disconnected) and will apply the changes I've made. So the question would be how would I prevent socket re-connection after I disconnect it? What would I add in the code above to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this:

```
ps -A | grep node
```

and you see one process, then this is your grep process. When you call grep it create grep process, show in output all matching processes (also grep process), and close grep process at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I prefer closing it programatically using nodejs and socket.io..